# Javascript - Bootstrap dropdown on hover open all menu levels of submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I already have javascript function that works well with dropdown list items which has just one dropdown-menu, but the problem occurs when I have dropdown list item with two or menu submenu levels, because on hover it opens all menu levels of submenu... Site is live, take a look - http://mile.x3.rs/mile/uram/

JavaScript that works fine with one dropdown-menu level

```js
// MENU HOVER
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown, .dropdown-active").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Partneri">Partneri <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#" title="Partner 1">Partner 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Partner 2">Partner 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Partner 3">Partner 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Partner 4">Partner 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Partner 5">Partner 5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Partner 6">Partner 6</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

But this

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Reference">Reference <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
      <a href="#" title="Prehrambena industrija">Prehrambena industrija</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Pivare">Pivare<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Please clarify if you want to open all sub levels or only the immediate children for the hovered element.  As stated your desired functionality is unclear.

Comment: If I have ex. References -> Food industry -> Brewery -> Heineken factory , on hover over References I want to open just Food Industry below, then when hover over Food Industry, on the right open Brewery etc.

Comment: Note on timing, I find the 500 value in the fadein to make the menu feel a bit sluggish.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and feedback as a site visitor, really appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to edit your jquery code to be like that .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown, .dropdown-active").hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').eq(0).stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').eq(0).stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

so the script will only run on the first element only .
https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/63Lfgjnm/

Comment: Now I notice that there is a problem when I try to open dropdown-submenu on mobile and tablet devices screen, when my navbar is collapsed. When I click on any of list item which has dropdown menu and dropdown submenu, it dropdown submenu doesn't open. How to fix ?

Comment: It doesn't work on touch devices because on those devices the click event considered as hover, so when you made your second click it consider that you want to hover out the li so it fade out the submenu. to fix this problem we will detect the device first and I made another script which will run on touch devices only. you will find it here : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/63Lfgjnm/3/ but I don't test it so please try it and tell me if you have any problem

Comment: Hmmm, very strange problem now... First click on li item (class dropdown), drop-down menu opens but immediately disappears. Second click on same list item (class dropdown), drop-down menu opens but with a different css style which I have defined (dont know why). Third click on dropdown-submenu, finally menu looks good as it should look like. Live example here - http://mile.x3.rs/mile/uram/

Answer (score 0):

You need to select **only direct descendants** of an element using jQuery's `find()`.

Try this and notice **`$(this).find('> .dropdown-menu')`**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown, .dropdown-active").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('> .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('> .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

Here is the full demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown, .dropdown-active").hover(function() {
    $(this).find('> .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).find('> .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <header>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Reference">Reference <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
          <a href="#" title="Prehrambena industrija">Prehrambena industrija</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Pivare">Pivare<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Option 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Option 2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.find` which traverses all descendants of the menu.  You only need the "next level" per your comment so you should use `.children` as that will not traverse to the next level.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown, .dropdown-active").hover(function() {
    $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/children/